# NGXS - defaults being optional values breaking state's model typing?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I a quick question on **defaults** values, as it's making me a bit confused.

Why is **defaults** value on the state optional? Wouldn't it mess up the typing and create many runtime errors if we forget to set defaults value?

```js
export class Increment {
    public static type = '[Counter] Increment';
}

@State<CounterStateModel>({
    name: 'counterState',
    // defaults: { 
    //     count: 0, // If I omit the defaults, then my state is actually undefined
    // },
})
@Injectable()
export class CounterState {
    @Selector()
    public static count(state: CounterStateModel): number {
        // That returns undefined, state is an empty object by default.
        // So a component that selects store.selectSnapshot(CounterState.count) will have wrong typing.
        return state.count; 
    }

    @Action(Increment)
    public increment({ setState, getState }: StateContext<CounterStateModel>): void {
        // This will try to add 1 to undefined, resulting in NaN. But getState() should be of type CounterStateModel..
        setState({ count: getState().count + 1 });
    }
}
```

I feel like **defaults** should be mandatory and of type of the state's model (`State<CounterStateModel>`, so **CounterStateModel** in my **example**). If I want the state's default value to be undefined, then the **CounterStateModel** should reflect that.

That raised my eyebrows a bit, and then combined with what I saw here https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/meta-reducer, where the example completely clears the global state without regards to the state's models, how does that not break everything?

I get that these are tools for us to use, so if I decide to clear all the state, I have to be aware of it and should resets to valid values (for all the states) once we log back in. I'm just confused with the ease of breaking the typing contracts of the state models.

Thanks!